# AngularJS: How can I append an element from a link function and have angular run a directive in it?

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives 'chart', and 'legend'.

From the chart directive I append

```
<legend forScope="' + scope.$id + '"></legend>
```

but the legend directive never runs. How do I get angular to process the legend element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at your code, it is not clear what are you doing. But generally, you will use the `$compile` service to compile the generated content before appending it to the dom. See [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)